# uploading files using jQuery and ajax gives error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to upload file using jQuery and ajax. But my code is not working. The selected file is not uploading.

//jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $('#form1'); // contact form
var submit = $('#upload');  // submit button
var alert = $('.alert1'); // alert div for show alert message

// form submit event
form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
    // sending ajax request through jQuery
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update_profile_pic.php', // form action url
        type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post
        dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml
        data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data 
        beforeSend: function() {
            alert.fadeOut();
            $('#img1').show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert.html(data).fadeIn(); // fade in response data
            form.trigger('reset'); // reset form
            $('#img1').hide();
            //window.location='update_profile.php';
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
});
});
```

//html code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
    <p><input type="file" class="textbox_black" name="profile_pic" required /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="update" value="Upload" class="button" id="upload" /></p>
</form>
```

//update_profile_pic.php

```
$profile_pic=   $_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"];
    $target_path=   "uploads/profile_pic/";
    $target_path=   $target_path.basename($profile_pic);

    if($profile_pic == "")
    {
        echo "* Select profile pic!";
    }
    else
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_pic']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
        {
            $result     =   mysql_query("UPDATE signup SET profile_pic='$target_path' WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());

            if($result)
            {
                echo "* Profile pic updated";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Something went wrong. Tryagain later!";
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any mistake in my coding. Is there any method to solve my issue. I have tried a lot to solve this problem, but no result.

Comment: @Farhan :- Selected file is not uploading

Comment: Add the error to you question statement

Comment: can you tell,what is the error,you are getting

Comment: @T.Rahgooy :- no error displaying.

Comment: If you open the page in question in Chrome, open Developer Tools, then load Console. Then if you run the upload function, it should come up with an error in the console (if it is a client side error).